# how did you learn to code? and what do you think is the best and most effective way?

Tags: javascript, html

How did you learn to code and get good at it? was it through school? through online resources or courses? or learning and figuring it out on your own? im new and im basically trying learn on my own with help of online resources mostly? any advice or tips?

Comment: First you need to understand algorithms and data flow (variables, conditionals, loops) then practice and patience, there are many resources in the web (freeCodeCamp, Codecademy, youTube)

Comment: There are some good online video courses for beginners (such as through Udemy), but it's hard to overstate the usefulness of `MDN`'s many spot-on guides and reference pages for Web development  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference). For JavaScript in particular, `javascript.info` is good too (https://javascript.info), and `JavaScript Allonge` is just excellent if you're interested in learning from a functional programming perspective (https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read#leanpub-auto-prelude-values-and-expressions-over-coffee).

Comment: The best way to learn how to code is to code!  To beginners this sounds counter intuitive but any coder worth his salt will tell you the same thing.  To get started I highly recommend the CS50 course intro to computers which you can find on edX for free!